# Find inverse matrix of $e^{At}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Find inverse matrix of $e^{At}$. I simply thought of $e^{A(-t)}$, knowing that $e^{At}e^{A(-t)}=e^{A(t+(-t))}=I$ $t$ is probably a complex number (It wasn't referred to in the exercise). Yet it was attributed a separate, sole question, and I therefore wonder if I truly get it right. I would appreciate your help.

Comment: You're right, because $\mathrm e^A\cdot \mathrm e^B=\mathrm e^{A+B}$ if $A$ and $B$ commute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

omitting the parameter $t$. For a matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ we have  that $A$ and $-A$ commute and therefore $$e^{A}e^{-A}=e^{A-A}=e^{0}=Id.$$ Since the inverse is unique we find that $(e^{A})^{-1}=e^{-A}$.